# why does SIGTERM handling mess up Pool.map() handling?

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, signals, pool

When I add signal handling, namely `SIGTERM`, to code that uses `multiprocessing.Pool.map()` in a cycle, it causes it to hang after nondeterministic number of iterations, at least with Python 3.8 on Ubuntu 20.04 (x86).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import threading
import signal
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count


def handler(num, frame):
    pass


def worker():
    pass


def runpool():
    work_tasks = []
    with Pool(processes=cpu_count()) as pool:
        try:
            results = pool.map(worker, work_tasks, 1)
        except Exception as exc:
            print("exc: {}".format(exc))


def worker_function():
    while True:
        print("run")
        runpool()

args = []
my_thread = threading.Thread(target=worker_function, name="my thread",
                             args=args, daemon=True)
my_thread.start()

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler)
while True:
    siginfo = signal.sigwaitinfo({signal.SIGTERM})
    print("got %d from %d by user %d\n" % (siginfo.si_signo,
                                           siginfo.si_pid,
                                           siginfo.si_uid))
```

Specifically, it is the `signal.signal()` call that leads to this behavior.

When run, this program prints bunch of `"run"` and hangs. The `KeyboardInterrupt` stack looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 355, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
```

Anyone know why is that ? Is this a limitation of Python itself or the above program is coded in a wrong way ?

I am aware that the pool handling sends `SIGTERM` to the pool workers via the context manager when the work is done so this behavior seems to be related.